# Number of solutions to binary matrix problem

Tags: matrices, optimization, binary-programming

I want to find the number of possible solution sets for this problem (so that I can compute probabilities later).

We want to find two matrices $A_{m \times n} = [a_{i,j}]$ 
and $B_{m \times n} = [b_{i,j}]$, such that,

$$ a_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}, b_{i,j} \in \{0,1\} $$
$$ \forall i, \sum_j{a_{i,j}} = 1 $$
$$ \forall i, \sum_j{b_{i,j}} = K_1  $$
$$ \forall j, \sum_i{(a_{i,j} + b_{i,j})} \leq K_2  $$
$$ \forall i, \forall j, a_{i,j} + b_{i,j} \leq 1  $$

Is there any way I can simplify this, so that it becomes easier to count the solution space?

Comment: The first constraint means only one entry per column is equal to 1 and everything else is 0.

Comment: Yes, each row in A sums to 1, each row in B sums to K1, each column in A+B is less than or equal to K2, and each element in A+B is 0 or 1.

Comment: The solution space seems to be O( number-of-columns ^ number-of-rows) or more accurately, 
O ( num-cols^num-rows x (num-cols choose K1)^num-rows)).